# Conectar Ruby on Rails a base MySQL

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, aplicación-web

Estuve intentando con el framework ruby on rails, pero he tenido problemas con la gema devise. Hice que funcionara pero sólo a nivel local con SQLite.

Me gustaría conectarme de forma remota a una base de datos en MySQL, para la creación del login y un sistema de citas.
Les dejo el codigo de mi database.yml en rails:

```
# SQLite version 3.x
#   gem install sqlite3
#
#   Ensure the SQLite 3 gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem 'sqlite3'
#
default: &default
  adapter: sqlite3
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
  database: db/development.sqlite3

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  <<: *default
  database: db/test.sqlite3

production:
  <<: *default
  database: db/production.sqlite3
```

Comment: Hola @Daniel. Bienvenido a [es.so]. Si bien se entiende hacia dónde apunta tu pregunta, hay algunas cosas que deberías considerar modificar para obtener respuestas a tu pregunta. La idea es que agregues el código con lo que intentaste, describiendo en qué exactamente no te está funcionando o dónde específicamente estás trabado. ¿Podrías **[edit]** la pregunta, siguiendo el formato descripto en la ayuda para presentar un [mcve]? Además, te recomiendo realizar el [tour]. Más info en [ask]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primero debes agregar la gema `mysql2` a tu archivo `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'mysql2'
```

Una vez que lo hagas, ejecuta el siguiente comando:

```
$ bundle install
```

Y, por último, agrega la configuración de tu base de datos en `config/database.yml`, por ejemplo<sup>1</sup>:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: nombre_de_la_base
  pool: 5
  username: tu_usuario
  password: tu_contraseña
```

Tu base de datos seguramente no ha sido creada, así que ejecuta los siguientes comandos:

```
$ rails db:create
$ rails db:migrate
```

<sup>1</sup> *Debes especificar la configuración también para las bases de datos `test` y `production`.*

Comment: ¿Funciona con devise? ¿Que sitio puedo utilizar para la base de datos? ya que hostinger no me muestra la cadena de conexion

Comment: @DanielTreviño Sí, funciona con Devise. En cuanto al hosting, prácticamente cualquier hosting de Rails te permite utilizar MySql; algunos ejemplos: [Engine Yard](https://www.engineyard.com/), [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/), [DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/), [Linode](https://www.linode.com/).  Hay varios más, te recomiendo ver cada uno ya que varian en complejidad y precio (PaaS vs IaaS) y selecciona uno de acuerdo a los _skills_ de th equipo.